# is there anyway to know server file directory structure in java?

Tags: java, security, remote-access

I am trying to access a remote file on a server just for study purposes.

My server is simple like below:

1. It is a basic SpringMVC Project
2. It shows an index.html which prints "HelloWorld" and the current server time

What I am trying to do is below:

1. Access URL(for instance, `http://192.168.0.1:8080/test`)
2. Find absolute path of index.html which is somewhere on the server (remote file)
3. Open and edit "HelloWorld" to "Hi, John!"

I already tried with HttpUrlConnection, but the methods of that class do not match my purposes. 
Second try was with File class. I put URI instance in File, but URI treats only "file://" protocol.

How can I change that text on the remote server computer?

Answer (score 1):

Basically I can show you **3** possible ways of which 2 are not utilizing code:

1. Use SSH to access the server and change the `index.html` using your favourity shell text editor (e.g. vi, nano etc.)
2. Use SFTP to access the server's file system and overwrite the `index.html` with a new version that contains the new string.
3. Create a `REST`-interface on your server that allows you to change the file contents. This one requires coding and I don't know if the amount of effort is really fitting your purposes.

**EDIT:**

You seem to want to change a remote file without any 'interaction' of this remote server, like a REST-interface or whatever. If this was possible so easily, it would pose a great security vulnerability to the system. Therefore you always need the interaction of the server, e.g. through a `REST`-interface or the like. You can not just type in some `Java` code and magically modify a remote file. The only thing that you can do with `Java` is to access the server via `ssh` or `HTTP` and utilize what the remote server offers you. That means that you will always have to do some work on your server side to make such a modification possible.

Comment: My purpose is control things with only java. #1, #2 can be a solution, but it needs server ID/PW. #3 needs extra work on server side which I do not wanted. Is there any way to do this with *ONLY* java? Thanks for an answer and editing :D

Comment: I think you have to at least do one of these 1. authenticate to server (with ID/PW even you do it with Java or not) to write the file 2. write some extra code to let the server write the file for you. So @nvrmnd answer maybe all the possible solutions

Comment: @Wittaya OK. But in that way my purpose is little bit useless. I was trying this since I want to know how hackers do redirection attack and prepare to defence this. I want to this, cause all of my services do not consider such attack. Anyway, Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, the following points will give you some assistence to achieve what you want:

- You should not modify server resource files within you application.
- Instead, use templating (see [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/)) to generate different versions of your index.html file.
- The content you are going to display ("Hello world" or "Hi, John") should be read from a database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB or whatever).
- If the caller must modify server content it should pass the content in POST request to the remote server, which in turn saves it in a DB or displays it directly via template.

However, if for some reasons (I do not know your requirements) you **must** access the file resource there is an  servlet API method you can use in your (remote) controller class:

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/index.html")!
```

This will give you a reference to you your index file (if your application is not packaged as a WAR!). Again, keep in mind that it is not recommended to fiddle around with server resource files.

**EDIT**

If you cannot change the remote server application and must use client side java, consider using an FTP or FTPS client: [Commons net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).